# SignalR keep table alive

Tags: signalr, real-time

I'm building a board game application using signalR, the application has a lobby page with table of connected players containing data such as status, points ect. which is suppose to be updated on real time,

I wonder if it's a good practice to keep the table always updated when thinking it may contain hundrends of lines with data and rows that constantly changes, would it be too much to the end point browser or too much traffic?

If it is,what's a bettet way to do so?

Comment: Instead of asking if hundreds of lines would be too much for the browser ask if this would be too much for the user. I don't think showing a few hundred constantly changing lines is useful for a user.

Comment: I agree it's intensive but if you're running a social network where you don't auto filter connected players, you have to display the entire list somehow, users are familiar with each other and might search individuals

Comment: You could show the "top 10" players which could update with SignalR real time and then provide a link/button/expand/etc... to show "all players".